# Is it possible to hide/remove the Category field on the Idea standard object?

Tags: ideas, categories, zone

**Case:** our company wants to simplify the Idea object (in order to retrieve maximum input & participation from the user community) and therefore skip Zone, Theme, Category from the user interface. Using configuration settings I managed to get rid of the 'Theme', but Zone & Category can not be easily removed (in the past we worked already w/ Ideas and defined a number of Zones). **It seems that you can't change/modify the Zone of an existing idea** (not even via DataLoader). As such we'll keep one Zone for all new ideas (the old Ideas will remain onder the Zone which was selected during the Idea creation).

---

**Workaround w/ visualforce page**

In order to simplify the input process I created a basic Visualforce page w/ 2 inputfields 'Idea.Title' & 'Idea.Body', nothing special but when pressing the 'Save' button we get the following message: `Error: Zone: Required fields are missing: [Zone]` and this is where I get stuck.

**Q)** How can I add a Zone field to the Visual Force Page below, assign a default value and keep it hidden (in the background) to avoid that it appears in the user interface?
I tried w/ ConnectionAPI & Zone as controller or extensionscontroller but w/o success.
Any suggestions?

```
<apex:page standardController="Idea" tabStyle="mySibelco__tab">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock title="Idea" helptitle="IdeaHelp" helpurl="/apex/mysibelcoIdeahelp">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="{!$Label.Edit_Button_Save}"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="{!$Label.Edit_Button_Cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons> 
<apex:pageblocksection title="Idea header" columns="1">
<apex:inputfield value="{!Idea.Title}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection> 
<apex:pageblocksection title="Idea details" columns="1">
<apex:inputfield value="{!Idea.Body}"/> 
</apex:pageblocksection> 
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Workaround w/o Visualforce page**

I found a possible workaround w/o using a Visualforce page through skipping the extra step to select the `Zone` by using the HTML link to the new page that you get just after selecting the (our default) Zone.

The only thing that's left now is the 'Category Field'.

**Q)** Any suggestion of how to hide or get rid o/t Category field (which is empty because we don't want to use it) on the standard Idea object? Creating a new page layout doesn't allow me to remove the category field, though the field is not on the layout it keeps showing up just beneath the 'Idea Description'.

Any idea how to change this behavior?

Comment: Eric, welcome to SF.SE. I've edited to your post to make all of it visible. I suggest you visit [Help] to learn how to better use the editor and how our site works to gain the most from your experience here. When pasting code, you'll want to select it, then click on the 'formatted code' button otherwise it will be hidden. In your case, that caused the remainder of your post to also be hidden. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be possible to Remove Category

[image]

Even in Help Page also it says the same thing [Help Page Idea](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=ideas_settings.htm&language=en_US), but wait for some time, some one who has worked on Ideas might give a clear picture

Comment: He might try filing a case with SF to see if they can help him remove it or if all the ideas in his database were updated to have the same Category applied to them, it *might* be possible to do the reversion; or at least make it possible for SF to do it for them. By having data where there's more than one category, that would indeed make it difficult to do.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yes.. that will be a good "Idea" !!!!!!!